# What is the importance end point mapping in USB?

Tags: usb

I am doing my project in USB.For that I need to know about End point Mapping in USB.Ingeneral End point is Buffer for storing information from the usb device before it send it via pipe to the host.so what is end point mapping??what is the Importance of end point mapping?

Answer (score 1):

The Source Doesn't contains the answer for the question what i am asking.It just gave plain information about how we able to get descriptors from USB Device.My intension is,suppose the device supports Multiple Interfaces,Each interfaces we assigned end points,How to avoid the same end point address or index again used in other interfaces?For that How to we write program for automatically detect The partcular end point address is already assigned?

Comment: That's what i am looking for... NO PROPER DOCS AVAILABLE.

Answer (score 0):

Each **endpoint**, in an interface, describes a single stream of input or output for the device. A device that supports streams for different kinds of functions has multiple interfaces. A device that supports several streams that pertain to a function can support multiple endpoints on a single interface.

All types of endpoints (except the default endpoint) must provide endpoint descriptors so that the host can get information about endpoint. An endpoint descriptor includes information, such as its address, type, direction, and the amount of data the endpoint can handle. The data transfers to the endpoint are based on that information.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Suppose in End point mapping I mapped the Address with its index value..How can i check whether the particular end point address is used again or Not?

Comment: Please refer the source that i gave